# Rails 4 - order by related models created_at - activity

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

In my rails app I have few related models for example:

Event

```
has_many :comments
has_many :attendents
has_many :requests
```

What I need is to order by 'created_at' but not only main model (Event) but also related models, so I will display on top of the list event with most recent activity i.e.: comments, attendents, requests

So if Event date is newer than any comment, request or attendent date this event will be on top. 
But if there is an event with newer comment this one will be on top etc.

How should I implement such ordering?

**EDIT**
db is mysql

Thanks

Comment: what db engine do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would place a column on the event for last_activity, and maintain it by touching from the associated models.

The alternative is to order by using a join or subquery against the other tables, which is going to require a database query that will be much less efficient than simply ordering by last_activity descending.

Comment: You could also use this approach and just touch the `updated_at` column on Event from the associated models instead of adding another column.

Answer (score 1):

```
Event
  .select("events.*")
  .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN comments ON comments.event_id = events.id")
  .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN attendents ON attendents.event_id = events.id" )
  .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN requests ON requests.event_id = events.id")
  .group("events.id")
  .order("GREATEST(events.created_at, 
          MAX(comments.created_at),
          MAX(attendents.created_at),
          MAX(requests.created_at)) DESC")
```

Comment: I think you want to order by max(events.created_at) etc.

Comment: What about performance? 
I have DB with ~300 000 Events and every event have  ~ 5 related entities.

Comment: Perfomance will be close to straight unindexed events ordering by `created_at` while joined tables are small. But could be significantly improved by David Aldridge's answer with index on last_activity_at

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, something like this

Firstly add this to your Models in question:

```
default_scope order('created_at DESC')
```

Then I would do some grouping:

```
@comments = Comment.all
@comments_group = @comments.group_by { |c| c.event}
```

And in your view you'll be able to loop through each block:

```
@comments_group.each do |event, comment|
  - event.name
  comment.each do|c|
    - c.body
```

I did not test this but it should give you an idea.